# Average value of Force in rotating bead using statistical physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Consider a mass m fixed to the middle point of a string of length $L$ whose extremities are a distance $$l$$ apart, and pulled with a tension $$F$$. The system is in thermal equilibrium, and one supposes that the only effect of thermal fluctuations is to make the system rotate about the horizontal (dashed) axis. As a result of this rotation, a tension force F arises along the string.

My hope is to show that $$<F> = \frac{l}{L^2-l^2}k_{B}T$$

First I succeeded in showing that $F = \frac{mv^2}{rsin\theta}$. Now I have to get the average of $F$. How and by which approach should I take?

The situation is:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a book source or can you include a diagram?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to take the average of the expression you have found for $F$. Since $r\sin\theta$ is a constant, you can simply take it out of the average. That means $<F> = {1 \over r\sin\theta} <mv^2>$. Write $r\sin\theta$ in terms of $l$ and $L$, put the average of $mv^2$ in its place, and you will be done.

Comment: how to find the average of $mv^2$?